# rebulid href tag from text with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have this dynamic html:

```
<div class="msg_body">
<p>
some text... |URI=http://www.somesite.co.il/|some link|EURI| some text |URI=http://www.somesite.co.il/|some link|EURI| , some text...
</p>
```

I need to extract the URI string and replace:

```
1. |URI= with [<a href"]
2. | with [>] 
3. |EURI| with [</a>]
```

so... I need it to bee like this:

```
<p>some text... <a href="http://www.somesite.co.il/" target="_blank"></a>some link</a> some text <a href="http://www.somesite.co.il/" target="_blank">some link</a> , some text...</p>
```

I stack at this point:

```
$('.msg_body').find('p').text().replace('|URI=','<a href="');
```

How can i do it in jquery?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex in the following way:

```
$('div.msg_body').html($('div.msg_body').html().replace(/\|URI=([^\|]+)\|/g, '<a href="$1" _target="blank">'));
$('div.msg_body').html($('div.msg_body').html().replace(/\|EURI\|/g, '</a>'));
```

**[Here's an example.](http://jsfiddle.net/NsNj7/)**

Or if you want something a little more concise (and cache the jQuery object) it can be shortened to:

```
var $msgBody = $('div.msg_body');
$msgBody.html($msgBody.html().replace(/\|URI=([^\|]+)\|/g, '<a href="$1">').replace(/\|EURI\|/g, '</a>'));
```

**[Here's an example.](http://jsfiddle.net/PJknB/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

The RegExp needs to be a bit more elaborate to do the job properly — I need a lot of trial and error to get the right regular expression for the job, so I use [tools like this](http://www.gethifi.com/tools/regex) to quickly figure out what I'm matching, what needs fixing, etc.

The full code for a solution, given your example, would be as follows:

```
var $target     = $('.msg_body p');

var text        = $target.text();

var replacement = text.replace(/\|URI=([^\|]+)\|([^\|]+)\|EURI\|/g, function(string, url, text){
  return '<a href="' + url + '">' + text + '</a>';
});

$target.html(replacement);
```

The `replace` method needs a function, because you're doing more than finding one piece of text and replacing it with another: you're capturing an elaborate string where you need to capture substrings and reconfigure them between pre-determined bits of code. [MDN explains using functions with `replace` pretty well in this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter).

Ultimately, the tricky bit is the regular expression itself:

```
/\|URI=([^\|]+)\|([^\|]+)\|EURI\|/g
```

The `g` at the end just means global (ie, replace every instance of this in the string), and the opening and closing `/`s are just notation for regular expressions. The `|` character has special meaning in regex (it stands for `OR`, meaning the sequence before it or after it are interchangeable), so you'll need to escape it by putting a slash in front of it: `\|`. What we then have is:

1. `\|URI=`: find a sequence starting with this string
2. `([^\|]+)`: capture a *group* — `()` — which consists of a character matching a *set* of rules — `[]` — those rules being anything that is *not* — `^` — the character `\|` (escaped `|`). Do this 1 or more times — `+`. This will essentially grab all characters until the next `|` and assign them to a group.
3. `\|`: the next character should be a `|`.
4. `([^\|]+)`: same as step 2, capture as a group again.
5. `\|EURI\|`: the end of the sequence.

So our function in the replace method always has the whole matched `string` as its first argument, but will also feature any groups in the expression as further arguments. The one in step 2 is our `url`, step 4 our `text`. Then we return the simple concatenation of HTML link syntax with the relevant components.

Here's the finished thing: http://jsfiddle.net/barney/B3E7N/